# how to print first word of dict of json?

Tags: python, json, printing

```
I am trying to read a json and want the output in excel so am trying to put dict in tabular format in excel.

**Code**

    f = open(filename, 'r') #open json file
        data = json.loads(f.read())    #load json
        for s in data['quiz']:     #finding 'quiz type in Json
            Quiz_Type = s     
            print(Quiz_Type)
```

### Data

```
{
    "quiz": {
        "sport": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "Which one is correct team name in NBA?",
                "options": [
                    "New York Bulls",
                    "Los Angeles Kings",
                    "Golden State Warriros",
                    "Huston Rocket"
                ],
                "answer": "Huston Rocket"
            }
        },
        "maths": {
            "q1": {
                "question": "5 + 7 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "10",
                    "11",
                    "12",
                    "13"
                ],
                "answer": "12"
            },
            "q2": {
                "question": "12 - 8 = ?",
                "options": [
                    "1",
                    "2",
                    "3",
                    "4"
                ],
                "answer": "4"
            }
        }
    }
}



i want print(Quiz_Type) o\p as Sport only..
but instead im getting Sport and Math
```

i got o/p:-
**maths**   Which one is correct team name in NBA?  New York Bulls||Los Angeles Kings||Golden State Warriros||Huston Rocket Huston Rocket

### maths   5 + 7 = ?   10||11||12||13  12  12 - 8 = ?  1||2||3||4  4

i need sport in place of 1st Math

Comment: Your JSON seems to be incomplete.

Comment: yes i have edited it now..

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use a library like xlsxwriter to write to write back to excel format. This library has comprehensive documentation:

https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/

Comment: I don't think he is seeking answer related to saving or doing stuff related to excel